# LSTM Keras ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.and Expected to see 1 array(s)

Tags: arrays, keras, lstm

I am running a model with the following specifications. Also this is being run in juptyer notebook run via the anaconda prompt.

```
# Import packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, LSTM, Flatten
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


seq=[]
lag_seq=[]
for i in range(100):
    list1=list()
    list2=list()
    for a in range(10):
        list1.append((a))
    for b in range(9):
        list2.append(b)

    seq.append(list1)
    lag_seq.append(list2)

seq=pd.Series(data=seq)
lag_seq=pd.Series(data=lag_seq)
data=seq.to_frame('SEQ')
data.insert(loc=1, column='LAG_SEQ',value=lag_seq)

targets=np.vstack((np.ones((50,2)), np.zeros((50,2))))
np.random.shuffle(targets)


trainX=data[0:70].values
trainY=data[0:70].values
testX=data[70:100].values
testY=data[70:100].values

trainX =np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0],trainX.shape[1],1))
testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0],testX.shape[1],1))

print(trainX.shape, trainY.shape, testX.shape, testY.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64,return_sequences=True,stateful=True,
           batch_input_shape=(1,2,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'],
         loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# Fit the Model
history = model.fit(list(trainX),trainY, epochs=20,verbose=0,shuffle=False,batch_size=(10))
```

I have also tried passing in a list of arrays as well when fitting and get the following error.

```
Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1000 arrays: [array([[list(['1', '9', '11', '10', '3', '9', '7', '7', '23', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
```

If I do not put `trainX` in a list I get this error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Are there any suggestions for remedying this?

Comment: Are you sure `trainX` is a numpy array of that shape? The error message strongly suggests that it's a python list with 1000 elements that are numpy arrays. Maybe you can post a complete self-contained example that we can run?

Comment: I posted a self contained contrived example to illustrate the problem. Albeit the actual y data has about 25 columns. There is a print statement to illustrate the shape of trainX. In the version that I was attempting trainX.shape returned (1000, 2, 1) after the reshape and (1000,2) prior to the reshape.

Answer (score 0):

If trainY is one-hot encoded with keras's to_categorical then 
in model.fit, use

```
np.array(trainY)
```

instead of

```
trainY
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the data is int or float? if it has object. It gets like the error.

So, you need check by `df.dtypes`.

```
print(data.dtypes)
```